# Angular2 webpack publish UglifyJs Unexpected token (SignalR, NullLogger)

Tags: angular, webpack, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I try to publish angular2 + SignalR project with webpack.

Project is works and published without UglifyJSPlugin

I want a minify JS code

With UglifyJSPlugin

**ERROR in dist/main.e0d2ac62d9e6f4ea96fd.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (NullLogger) [dist/main.e0d2ac62d9e6f4ea96fd.bundle.js:4779,6]**

**NullLogger** - [from SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Net)

webpack.prod.js

```js
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

new UglifyJSPlugin({
    parallel: {
        cache: true,
        workers: 2
    },
    warnings: true
  }),
```

[I was used this - not help](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/867)

**What i can looked to fix**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is problem in UglifyJs library, because it doesn't supporting ES6. Check [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/867) and possible fix in [damienbod answer](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/867#issuecomment-329114305).